# JSF h:outputStylesheet id attribute not working

Tags: css, jsf, jsf-2

I have a strange behavior of [h:outputStylesheet](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputStylesheet.html).
I need to give an Id to my stylesheet in order to change it via jQuery.

But the weird thing the tag doesn't render the "link" tag with an ID !

Here's my Code

```
<h:outputStylesheet  id="skinstyle" library="default" name="css/style.red.css" />
```

and the output is this

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/MyApp/faces/javax.faces.resource/css/style.red.css?ln=default">
```

I've got Mojarra 2.1.11 ,jBoss 7.1.3, Primefaces 3.5 (although Primefaces has nothing todo with this, just saying)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a bug in jsf implementation...

Meanwhile as workaround to access your link and modify you can try using jquery selector

For example:

```
$(document).find("link[href*='part_of_your_css_name']").attr("new_css_name"),
```

Comment: it seems to be.. I also just tested with Mojarra 2.1.5 the same (as a desperate move).. anyway I have to do some modifications to the files names in order to find with jQuery :) Thank you.